# How to run many instances of the same process in a resource constraint environment without duplicating memory content

Tags: linux, process

I observe that each ffmpeg instance doing audio decoding takes about 50 mb of memory. If I record 100 stations, that's 5 GB of RAM.

Now, they all more or less use the same amount of RAM, I suspect the contain the same information over and over again because they are spawned as new processes rather than forked.

Is there way to avoid this duplication?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, they all more or less use the same amount of RAM, I suspect the
> contain the same information over and over again because they are
> spawned as new processes rather than forked.

Have you considered that the processes may use about the same amount of RAM because they are performing roughly the same computation, with similar parameters?

Have you considered that whatever means you are using to compute memory usage may be insensitive to whether the memory used is attributed *uniquely* to the process *vs*. already being shared with other processes?

> Is there way to avoid this duplication?

Programs that rely on shared libraries *already* share those libraries' executable code among them, saving memory.

Of course, each program does need its own copy of any writable data belonging to the library, some of which may turn out to be unused by a particular client program, and programs typically have memory requirements separate from those of any libraries they use, too.  Whatever amount of that 50 MB per process is in fact additive across processes is going to be from these sources.  Possibly you could reduce the memory load from these by changing program parameters (or by changing programs), but there's no special way to run the same number of instances of the program you're running now, with the same options and inputs, to reduce the amount of memory they use.

Comment: Can I assume the OS will page out whatever is not needed? I assume it does not take 50 mb to decode an mp3 file.

Comment: @LemonSky, yes, you can anticipate that the OS will page out unused memory attributed to the program, at least if there is pressure on the available RAM.  Note also that although I agree that it should not *need to* take 50 MB to decode an mp3 file, that's a different question from whether the program you're using, in the environment where you're using it, actually *does* require that much memory.